# Can this design be simplified? (Visitor with Generics)

Tags: c#, .net, oop, unity-game-engine

**Code:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/09sOyG

**Intent:** 
There is a library with a set of basic actions, and the concrete modules should add more, but the library should support them.
The actions are sent to the system and then the specific instances are recovered and handled.
Everything needs to be statically typed and and verified in compile-time.

**Current solution:**
Since there is no double-dispatch, I used the visitor pattern.
Using generics to provide different implementations of the visitation, extending the base one.
I wrap the basic actions to run them through the concrete instance.
I am not completely sure that I am using generics properly for this case.

**Problems:**
Wrapping top level actions seems far from ideal and I want to be able to add layered actions (each module extends the possible operations) without having system-level implications. Also the code looks convoluted.

### Is there any way to remove the wrapper?

Basically to be able to do something like:

```
runner.Execute(new BaseAction1()));
runner.Execute(new ConcreteAction1());
```

Instead of:

```
runner.Execute(new BaseActionWrapper(new BaseAction1()));
runner.Execute(new ConcreteAction1());
```

while still be able to recover the specific instances on the listener:

```
public void Visit(BaseAction1 action){}
public void Visit(ConcreteAction1 action){}
```

Notes:

- No use of 'dynamic' keyword, runtime does not support it (Unity - Old C# version)
- No runtime type reflection please, typeof(), GetType() or "Is - As"

Comment: OOP is bad? you may want to review this opinionated statement.

Comment: I did not mean that, I said to avoid comments like "oop is bad, prefer a functional solution", which is an answer I got often. But I understand how it could be misinterpreted, thanks.

Comment: The code _is_ very convoluted, but if you can change all your actions inherit from a base class, you have a single `Execute` without having to create wrappers. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ixuKHG